# How to get head's angles from camera?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

Recently,I worked on a project which allow me to get head's information from two cameras.I got the head's position some days ago,using the disparity and get the position by reprojectTo3D().I also want to get the value of head's angle,but I don't know what to do them.Do anyone can help me? Just some advice is okay.Thank you!

Comment: take a look at [dlib](http://blog.dlib.net/2014/08/real-time-face-pose-estimation.html)

Comment: Thank you.But does that program simply mark some characteristic points? I'm not very sure how to get the angle from that program.Does this program can get angles?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/36240309/5294258